# Flatten unable to infer sequence types?

Tags: scala

Given the following code, which correctly understands to generate a `Seq[String` :

```
  val ac: Seq[Seq[String]] = a.map(_.devents.map(_.toValidString))
  val ac2: Seq[String] = ac.flatten
```

However using the chain/builder pattern with `flatten` *directly* ie without explicitly providing the return type is *not* working:

```
  val ac: Seq[String] = a.map(_.devents.map(_.toValidString)).flatten
```

The type of `ac` is inferred as Seq[**Nothing**] by the scala interpreter.

Why is `flatten` unable to infer the type?  Is there a better/more succint workaround then the full two lines of code shown in the first snippet?

Comment: This would be easier to answer with complete examples. It's also unclear why you have nested `Seq`s in the type on your second `ac`—aren't you expecting them to be flattened?

Comment: @TravisBrown  Thx  I fixed the expected type of `ac2` in the op (it was a miscopy from the actual code) .  I tried to provide complete example but the ones I put together *are* working: so i'm relegated to asking for guidelines w/o the concise examples demonstrating it.

Comment: @javadba what's the type of `devents`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella  devents is a case class `DerivedEvent` to which a method `toValidString` was added that returns a String

Comment: By "the scala interpreter" do you mean the REPL or is it the type shown in IDE (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA)?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Intellij interpreter. But I did not *only* trust the interpreter (which does get confused at times..):  also the IJ compiler also complains the same way.